# Can I just differentiate my Euler rates to get the angular rates?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-dynamics

There is this matrix:

$${W_{\eta}}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin(\theta) & 0 & 1 \\
\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

(some other sources change the basis of this matrix so becomes mirrored). My background is robotics. When I need to find the Lagrangian (for the dynamics) I need to describe the rotational energy. This done like this: $E_{rot}=\dot{\eta}J\dot{\eta}$ where $\dot{\eta}$ is the angular velocity and $J$ is the global inertia matrix. I would have differentiated my Euler angles and call it a day. However, that is wrong.

$\dot{\eta}$ are the Euler rates and $v$ is the angular rates. And I have my Euler rates by differentiating my roll, pitch and yaw so do I have to do this to get my angular rates ([source](https://www.mecharithm.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/quadrotor_dynamics.pdf)):

$ v={W_{\eta}}^T\dot{\eta}$?

Also why can't I assume Euler rates = angular rates?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, there are also similar questions in physics like: [How to compute the angular velocity from the angles of a rotation matrix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293037/37995).

Comment: While the question itself is not a dup, it is, I think, fully answered here: [What is the difference between Body Pitch Rate and Inertial Pitch Rate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/what-is-the-difference-between-body-pitch-rate-and-inertial-pitch-rate/52758#52758). Basically, Euler angles (and their rates) relate to the ground, while "angular rates" (those you mean) are _body_ angles/rates. They are just in different frames of reference. Rotation between them is not the same as for linear quantities because you need to preserve angular momentum.

Comment: @Zeus Can you explain how that matrix was obtained?

Comment: @Hamzalihi, this is exactly your matrix, inverted (to calculate Euler rates from body angular velocities, which is a more common problem in avionics, to which that question is related). Except that columns are arranged differently because of the velocity vector convention (mine is in the order of axes: [$\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z$], or [P, Q, R], while yours in the order of rotations: [yaw, pitch, roll]; you mention this issue re "mirrored" matrix). This matrix is not orthogonal, so it's not enough to transpose it for the opposite conversion. That's probably the source of your confusion.